# R: change columns names of multiple tables

Tags: r

I read in multiple .csv and now want to change all their column names in a loop. I could only find out how to change the names of a single table:

```
colnames(w01_10temp) <- c("date", "time", "temp", "na")
```

I also nee .csv files in R. Before I had:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd()) 
numfiles <- length(filenames) 
for (all_temp in c(1:numfiles)) {
filenames[all_temp] <- paste(filenames[all_temp],sep="")
assign(gsub([.]ASC$","temp",filenames[all_temp]),read.delim2(filenames[all_temp], fileEncoding="ISO-8859-15", skip = 4))    }
```

So I tried putting the lapply in the loop, without success:

```
for (all_temp in lapply(filenames,myReadTable)) {
  filenames[all_temp] <- paste(filenames[all_temp],sep="")
  }
```

Comment: I've no idea what you expect a line like `filenames[all_temp] <- paste(filenames[all_temp],sep="")` will achieve. Anyway: if I understand your last problem correctly: change @mbq's myReadTable's second line (with the `read.table`) to `x<-read.delim2(filenames[all_temp], fileEncoding="ISO-8859-15", skip = 4)`. The result will be a list holding all the tables for each file, with the correct column names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a wrapper function:

```
myReadTable<-function(file){
 read.table(file,...)->x
 names(x)<-c("date","time","temp","na")
 return(x)
}
```

And then `lapply` it over the file name vector to get a list of data frames (this is much more manageable than using global variables).

```
lapply(c('fileA.csv','fileB.csv','fileC.csv'),myReadTable)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do this with an automatically created name vector containing all files? The file list is very long and not continous, like: 1.csv 3.csv 4.csv 6.csv

Comment: @tomtomme Just by `lapply(file_name_vector,myReadTable)`... If you have this list as a single string, `strsplit` may help in converting it into a vector.